# Passing values to components angular

Tags: angular, components

```
    async loadBarchart() { 
           let tmp = await this.http.get<any>(environment.endpoint + '/api/dashboard/corrosionstudy/' + this.idToUse).toPromise();

    //make sure the data that is shown is from the last plantItem that was clicked on in the tree
    if (this.idToUse !== activeId) {
      return;
    }

    this.dataObject = tmp;
    
    this.loops = tmp.loops;
    this.selectedLoops = this.loops;
    this.theoreticalStudies = tmp.theoreticalStudies;
    this.damageMechanisms = tmp.damageMechanisms;
    this.appliedDamageMechanisms = tmp.appliedDamageMechanisms;
    this.librariesForDamageMechanisms = tmp.librariesForDamageMechanisms;

      this.graphData = [
        { name: this.graphLabels[0], value: this.loops.length},
        { name: this.graphLabels[1], value: this.theoreticalStudies.length},
        { name: this.graphLabels[2], value: this.damageMechanisms.length},
        { name: this.graphLabels[3], value: this.appliedDamageMechanisms.length}
      ];

    this.graphData = this.graphData.map(item => ({ ...item }));
}
```

When i pass the graphData to another component i get undefined besides it has value why that?

```
<app-dashboard-horizontal-barchart [labels]="graphLabels" [(items)]="graphData"
     [labelBootstrapColumnNumber]="cardLabelBootstrapColumnNumber" 
     [componentWidth]="componentWidth" canSelect="true" (selectionChanged)="onSelect($event)">
</app-dashboard-horizontal-barchart>
```

Code of the typescript of the child component

```
  //items
@Input() public items: { name: string, value: number }[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
//1) check for items
this.itemsFound = false;
console.log(this.items);

if(this.items.length > 0) {
  for (let item of this.items) {
    if (item.value > 0) {
      this.itemsFound = true;
    }
    
    if (this.canSelect) {
      this.actualLabels.push(item.name);
    }
  }
}
```

I post an image from my debugging process...NOTE that dashboard is the parent component and dashboard-horizontal is the child
[image]

Comment: please share more code, like that of the child, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Answer (score 1):

It could just be a timing issue, where `ngOnInit` gets fired before `loadBarchart` completed, so just move the code into a separate method, then call it using a `@ViewChild` like so.

child component

```
  //items
@Input() public items: { name: string, value: number }[] = [];


  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  initialize(): void {
        //1) check for items
        this.itemsFound = false;
        console.log(this.items);

        if(this.items.length > 0) {
           for (let item of this.items) {
             if (item.value > 0) {
               this.itemsFound = true;
             }
    
             if (this.canSelect) {
               this.actualLabels.push(item.name);
             }
           }
         }
  }
}
```

parent component ts

```
 @ViewChild('dashboardHorizontalBarchart') dashboardHorizontalBarchart: DashboardHorizontalBarchart;

 async loadBarchart() { 
           let tmp = await this.http.get<any>(environment.endpoint + '/api/dashboard/corrosionstudy/' + this.idToUse).toPromise();

    //make sure the data that is shown is from the last plantItem that was clicked on in the tree
    if (this.idToUse !== activeId) {
      return;
    }

    this.dataObject = tmp;
    
    this.loops = tmp.loops;
    this.selectedLoops = this.loops;
    this.theoreticalStudies = tmp.theoreticalStudies;
    this.damageMechanisms = tmp.damageMechanisms;
    this.appliedDamageMechanisms = tmp.appliedDamageMechanisms;
    this.librariesForDamageMechanisms = tmp.librariesForDamageMechanisms;

      this.graphData = [
        { name: this.graphLabels[0], value: this.loops.length},
        { name: this.graphLabels[1], value: this.theoreticalStudies.length},
        { name: this.graphLabels[2], value: this.damageMechanisms.length},
        { name: this.graphLabels[3], value: this.appliedDamageMechanisms.length}
      ];

    this.graphData = this.graphData.map(item => ({ ...item })); 
    if(this.dashboardHorizontalBarchart) {
        this.dashboardHorizontalBarchart.initialize();
    }
}
```

parent component html

```
<app-dashboard-horizontal-barchart #dashboardHorizontalBarchart [labels]="graphLabels" [(items)]="graphData"
     [labelBootstrapColumnNumber]="cardLabelBootstrapColumnNumber" 
     [componentWidth]="componentWidth" canSelect="true" (selectionChanged)="onSelect($event)">
</app-dashboard-horizontal-barchart>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help but did not work for me.

Comment: @Sotiris If you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated I will check!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```
  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadBarchart();
  }
```

I created the ngAfterViewInit in the parent component .It is part of the Angular component lifecycle, and it is triggered once the component's view and its child views (if any) have been created.